# iterating through array values to implement individually in a function

Tags: python, physics

I need to make it so I can return the function (abspec2(v)) for each value of the array row, and sum each returned function for each value of the row (not sum each value of the array). apologies if my code is unclear, quite new to this. Please comment if you require clarification.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df =pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\adamf\OneDrive\Desktop\hitran_water.csv')
print(df)

arr = df.to_numpy()
```

here I am setting my variables, setting i as the row value. I need to be able to calculate and return the below function (abspec2(v), for each individual row value of each column.

```
nu0 = arr[i,1]

s = arr[i,2]

gamma = arr[i,3]

def abspec2(v):
    a = s1/np.pi
    b = gamma/(gamma**2+(v - nu0)**2)
    spec = a*b
    return spec




plt.plot(V, abspec2(V))
plt.show()

dput(C:\Users\adamf\OneDrive\Desktop\hitran_water.csv)
```

Comment: [A sample of your data, your expected output and reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful to answer your question. Your function seems trivial to vectorize, there is no need to iterate over the array.

Comment: essentially I have a very long .csv file with data regarding the absorption spectra of water. I need to calculate that function for each row value of the variables, and then sum together each function return in order to plot it against V (V = np.arange((10**4)/0.85,(10**4)/0.8, 0.01)

Comment: We don't need the domain context of your program. We need sample data to enshure our solution will run and outputs the desired result.